# I can't find GoogleSignInClient()

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use the Friebase Google Authentication in my project, but the GoogleSignInClient() isn't even found in the Android Studio.

I already using the Firebase to create and login users with email and password, so the Firebase is OK. But is my first time using the Google Authenticator.

Here's my code:

MainActivity:

```
private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
```

Build Gradle (Firebase Dependencies):

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0'
```

================================================================

**> I SOLVED IT!**
I just updated the "com.google.gms.google-services" version in the build.gradle(app-name) file!